# Appcelerator Titanium - unable to run on android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-android

I was able to run on Android but since upgrading to the latest SDK (6.2.0.GA) I'm unable to run. I was getting an error telling me that my Android SDK is not updated and I should update to the latest. So I did. Now I'm getting a different error:

```
[ERROR] :  Missing required Android SDK tools: zipalign, aapt, aidl, dx
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  The Android SDK located at /Users/ophir/Library/Android/sdk-titanium has incomplete or out-of-date packages.
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Current installed Android SDK tools:
[ERROR] :    Android SDK Tools:          25.2.5
[ERROR] :    Android SDK Platform Tools: 26
[ERROR] :    Android SDK Build Tools:    not installed
```

I ran `appc ti setup check` and it also yield the same errors about the missing items:

```
  ✕  android            "android" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK
  ✓  emulator           installed /Users/ophir/Library/Android/sdk-titanium/tools/emulator
  ✓  mksdcard           installed /Users/ophir/Library/Android/sdk-titanium/tools/mksdcard
  ✕  zipalign           "zipalign" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK
  ✕  aapt               "aapt" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK
  ✕  aidl               "aidl" executable not found; please reinstall Android SDK
```

I'm running on MAC OS X. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TiSDK 6.2.0 you need build tools 25 and you need Android 25 SDK installed. If you open up the SDK manager you can select the build tools you want by going to the build tools tab. You can expand the details so you can specify what version you want.

It is also recommend to put the version in the manifest part in tiapp.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the Android SDK files? Seems to be the error you're getting.